# Add AD Groups to Sharepoint Online Group using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, csom, pnp-js

I have the following situation:

AD:

- Users
- Groups (Type: Security and Office365)

Sharepoint:

- Groups

The hole point is to add both the users and the groups from AD to Sharepoint. I got adding the users to work using the following code:

```
User adUser = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(ad.LogOnName);
ctx.Load(adUser);
gc.Users.AddUser(adUser);
ctx.Load(gc, x => x.Users);
```

Where the LogOnName is the User Principal Name of the user. When adding the groups as LogOnName is used the group name.

Any suggestions where I am mistaken wehn adding the groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my sample tested code for your reference:

```
User group = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("SecurityGroup");
ctx.Load(gc);
User addUser=gc.Users.AddUser(group);
ctx.Load(addUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```